# How to use arm-linux-androideabi compiler

Tags: android, c++, linux, gcc, android-ndk

I wonder how to use `arm-linux-androideabi` compiler.
That compiler is on `android-ndk` tool.

There is `ndk-build` tool on `android-ndk` tool. To compile ethercat stack, I need only `arm-linux-androideabi` compiler.

But, I saw this message.

```
root@ubuntu:/opt/android/android-ndk-r9c/jni# arm-linux-androideabi-gcc -o test test.c
/opt/android/android-ndk-r9c/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.6/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.6/../../../../arm-linux-androideabi/bin/ld: error: cannot open crtbegin_dynamic.o: No such file or directory
/opt/android/android-ndk-r9c/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.6/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.6/../../../../arm-linux-androideabi/bin/ld: error: cannot open crtend_android.o: No such file or directory
/opt/android/android-ndk-r9c/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.6/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.6/../../../../arm-linux-androideabi/bin/ld: error: cannot find -lc
/opt/android/android-ndk-r9c/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.6/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.6/../../../../arm-linux-androideabi/bin/ld: error: cannot find -ldl
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

How am I supposed to do this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to let the compiler know where to look for these files.
Try using:

```
arm-linux-androideabi-gcc --sysroot=/opt/android/android-ndk-r9c/platforms/android-19/arch-arm -o test test.c
```

where 19 is android API level you want to use. You can find more info on docs/STANDALONE-TOOLCHAIN.html in your ndk dir.